# SimpleDateFormat is missing short and long time patterns

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, time-format

Is there a reason why `SimpleDateFormat` has no "t" and "T" similar to c#?
For example if you want to have a custom format and not worry about 24hour or 12am/pm formats; also Egypt has its own format

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

[image]

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)` will give you the short time pattern repsecting usage of 12 or 24 hours clock for the default locale. Similar for `FormatStyle.LONG`. Use that formatter for formatting a `LocalTime` or other java.time class that holds a time of day (such as for example `ZonedDateTime`).

Comment: *Is there a reason*? This is because they were not in Sun’s and Oracle’s design for Java and Goggle did not add them later for Android. I also believe that `t` and `T` are not in the Unicode standard that inspired the design.

Comment: It may also be part of the story that C# was designed later than Java and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I don’t think it makes any sense to compare the format pattern letters of [Micorsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) with those of Java that you link to. The two sets are built from completely different philosophies, and I don’t see any similarity.

Comment: @OleV.V. i see differences ms one is better :D

Comment: It depends on your purpose. If MS is better for your purpose, then it is so.

Comment: @OleV.V. It depend on purpose its just better SDF is not as advanced period. But thats the discussion for forum not stack overflow